# How to use if else in awk?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a text file and it's contents are like below,

`foo.txt`

```
firefox:
Installed: 24.0+build1-0ubuntu1
Candidate: 24.0+build1-0ubuntu1
```

I want to print the first field in the first line if the value of `Installed` and the `Candidate` are not same.If it's  same then empty output is enough.

I tried,

```
cat foo.txt | awk '$1~/^Installed:/ {var=$2;next} $1~/^Candidate:/ {var1=$2;next} NR==1 {pkg=$1} {if(var != var1) { print pkg;} }'
```

But it displays nothing.It would be better if you provide an awk solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close:

```
$ cat foo.txt
firefox:
Installed: 24.0+build1-0foo
Candidate: 24.0+build1-0bar

$ awk '$1~/^Installed:/ {var=$2;next} $1~/^Candidate:/ {var1=$2;next} NR==1 {pkg=$1} END {if(var != var1) { print pkg;} }' foo.txt
firefox:
```

Comment: And one more, i don't want the `:` at the last of firefox.

Comment: Is that necessary to use `END` at the last?

Comment: No, you could alternatively perform the test in the block where you find Candidate or you could add a test for var and var1 are non-null. It just has to be done somewhere after all of your variables have been populated. wrt removing `:`, see `sub()` in the man page or set `FS=":[[:space:]]+"`.